# How do I force AWS Cognito to retrieve an IdentityId from the server?

Tags: amazon-cognito

In the iOS SDK (v2.4.8) I can't logout a user and then login as a different user correctly.

The (correct) cognityIdentityId returned by AWS for the first user (since an app start) is also returned for the second user (unless the app is restarted). This gives access to the AWSCognitoDataset of one user by another.

I think this is because the iOS SDK has cached the id and the documented call to clear that cache, doesn't fully work.

When logging in:

```
// one-off initialisation
```

self.credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityPoolId:Constants.CognitoIdentityPoolId)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider:self.credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    …
    // I get idToken from my external provider serice (Auth0)
    func doAmazonLogin(idToken: String, success : () -> (), _ failure : (NSError) -> ()) {
        var task: AWSTask?

```
    //Initialize clients for new idToken
    if self.credentialsProvider?.identityProvider.identityProviderManager == nil || idToken != Application.sharedInstance.retrieveIdToken() {
        let logins = [Constants.CognitoIDPUrl: idToken]
        task = self.initializeClients(logins)
    } else {
        //Use existing clients
        self.credentialsProvider?.invalidateCachedTemporaryCredentials()
        task = self.credentialsProvider?.getIdentityId()
    }
    //Make login
    task!.continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error != nil) {
            failure(task.error!)
        } else {
            // the task result will contain the identity id
            let cognitoId:String? = task.result as? String
            self.customIdentityProviderManager!.addToken(Constants.CognitoIDPUrl, value:idToken)
            //Store Cognito token in keychain
            Application.sharedInstance.storeCognitoToken(cognitoId)
            success()
        }
        return nil
    }
}

func initializeClients(logins: [NSObject:AnyObject]?) -> AWSTask? {
    //Create identity provider managet with logins
    let manager = CustomIdentityProviderManager(tokens: logins!)
    self.credentialsProvider?.setIdentityProviderManagerOnce(manager)        
    return self.credentialsProvider?.getIdentityId()
}
```

When logging out:

```
// Clear ALL saved values for this provider (identityId, credentials, logins). [docs][1]
let keychain = A0SimpleKeychain(service:"…")
keychain.clearAll()
```

I've also tried adding:

```
credentialsProvider!.clearCredentials()
credentialsProvider!.clearKeychain()
```

Is anyone using the AWS iOS SDK and has coded logout successfully such that a new user can login cleanly?

There is the oddly named method `credentialsProvider.setIdentityProviderManagerOnce()` - I can't find this documented but its name suggests that it should only be called once per session. But if `keychain.clearAll()` removes `logins` then one would need to call `setIdentityProviderManagerOnce` each time a new user logins in in order to setup `logins` each time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe your login/logout flow a bit more? Cognito doesn't support multiple logins from the same provider per identity, so it sounds like, unless you're using multiple, it isn't actually changing the identity.

In any case, have you tried the [clearKeyChain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html#//api/name/clearKeychain) method on the credentials provider? It's largely for use cases like this - clearing everything.

Comment: I've added code snippets to my Q. What I want to achieve is to allow an account to be logged out of. And then if a different user account is logged into, to get a different cognitoIdentityId. i.e. I don't want the second account to be merged or polluted by the first. Currently, the app needs to be restarted after the "logout" and after the restart the login process gets the correct cognitoIdentityId. Without the restart, the second login gets the first account's cognitoIdentityId

Comment: It looks like you're using authenticated identities, setting a login. This should always give you the same ID when signing in. Is the reboot case not setting a token in the request, but the non reboot is?

Comment: I only suggest that because clearKeyChain is the way to go to sign out. It nukes everything

Comment: That must be where the bug lies. clearKeychain isn't nuking the cached cognitoIdentityId as expected. After calling clearKeychain() my app can still get access to the previous cognito id unless I restart the app - after a restart the value has gone. Can this be submitted as a bug?

Comment: Apple won't accept apps that exit themselves so I can't kill the app "forcing" users to start the app. An awkward workaround in any case - but Apple blocks it.

Comment: You will be able to reproduce the problem using this project: https://github.com/iuliiazhelem/Auth0CognitoIntegration (though you'd need an Auth0 account)

Comment: The issue isn't with clearKeyChain(). I just noticed you're using user pools as a provider, you also need to sign out that user. Call signOut() on that user while calling clearKeyChain(), let me know if that works.

Comment: actually I'm using Federated Identities rather than User Pools. I'm guessing 'signOut' isn't available for Federated Identities.

Comment: It looks like you're adding a user pools token to your identity pool, and I believe CognitoIdpUrl is the key for the user pools token. Can you double check that? SignOut is called on the user who has signed in to get that idToken.

Comment: I have set CognitoIDPUrl to a unique string identifying the authentication provider for my service. My AWS account does not define or use any user pools.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try an older version of the Cognito iOS sdk - when public access to "logins" and a function "refresh()" was implemented. Not ideal as I'll be heading in the wrong direction :)

Comment: This (rather long) thread suggests developers started having this problem with the release of v2.4.0 of the sdk https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/357